# Exponentiated Commutation Relations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator

A proof about the exponentiated commutation relations is mentioned In [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-7116-5) page 285:

> The exponentiated momentum operators satisfy:
>
> $(e^{itP_j}\psi)(\textbf{x})=\psi(\textbf{x}+t\hbar \textbf{e}_j)$.
>
> It is then evident that $e^{isP_j}$  commutes with $e^{itP_k} $.

I know that the same operators of different indices commute. But I cannot see (mathematically) the conclusion that the author stated in this particular example.

Comment: @G.Smith Sorry I had to edit the equation. I forgot the $e$ of the unit vector.

Comment: The effect of this operator is to shift the position, i.e. adding a displacement to $\vec{x}$. Since it's addition, it's abelian. To be precise, try acting two operators in different directions on the state, the net result doesn't depend on in which direction you move first.

Comment: @M.Zeng You mean I can apply the exponentiated operators in this way: $(e^{itP_k}e^{isP_j} \psi) (\textbf{x})$ and then use the Baker-Hausdorff-Lemma ??

Comment: You can use the BH formula of course. But what I meant was exactly the provided in the answer below, i.e. by looking at their effect on the position. It's mathematically sound and more intuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It is not true that "the same operator with different indices commute". For example, the angular momentum operators in different directions don't commute, i.e., $[\hat{L}_x,\hat{L}_y]\neq 0$, etc. However, of course, what you say is true of momentum operators (and position operators), i.e., $[\hat{p}_x,\hat{p}_y]=0$, etc. (at least in [commutative geometries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncommutative_geometry)).
- Given that $e^{i\hat{P}_jt}\psi(\mathbf{x})=\psi(\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{e}_j)$, you can see that $$e^{i\hat{P}_kt}e^{i\hat{P}_jt}\psi(\mathbf{x})=\psi(\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{e}_j+t\mathbf{e}_k)=\psi(\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{e}_k+t\mathbf{e}_j)=e^{i\hat{P}_jt}e^{i\hat{P}_kt}\psi(\mathbf{x})$$Thus, $[e^{it\hat{P}_j},e^{it\hat{P}_k}]=0$. To directly see that this implies $[\hat{P}_j,\hat{P}_k]=0$, notice that since $[e^{it\hat{P}_j},e^{it\hat{P}_k}]=0$ is generically true, you can take the limit $t\to0$ and write $[1+it\hat{P}_j,1+it\hat{P}_k]=0$, or, $[\hat{P}_j,\hat{P}_k]=0$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I forgot about the angular momentum operators. But Shouldn't it be that $t$ goes to infinity?

Comment: @Sally I couldn't understand your suggestion of taking $t\to\infty$. Can you elaborate? Are you asking the validity of this result at $t\to\infty$ or are you asking that we should take $t\to\infty$ limit to arrive at the desired result instead of the $t\to 0$ limit?

Comment: I got it now. You have used the expansion of the exponential for small variables. Thank you.